NATted requests redirected to local host fail!
using AT&T's Internet Air, with the Wistron CGW450-400 unit, I'm routing all incoming traffic to a local internal host.  I have a domain bound to the external IP address and serve a web site and mail at that location.  it all works except for one thing: when I'm on the local net, my requests go out to the external address (I'm hitting the domain) via the NAT.  the request has to be routed back into the localnet host, which seems to fail.  therefore I can pick up e-mail from the server when I'm outside the house but now when I'm in the house.  if I change the mail server address to use the local (internal) IP address, it's all good, but this is not a workable solution for me
I've looked up and down the configuration for that unit and cannot find a setting that would allow it to redirect NAT requests back into the local net.  how is this handled?
